# read method for jTextArea makes BufferedReader null

Tags: java, null, bufferedreader, jtextarea

I'm trying to use read method for jTextArea from BufferedReader. It works and my text appears in jTextArea successfully. but after using read method it makes BufferedReader null. Here is my example code:

```
    private void Calculate() throws IOException{
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) ;

            jTextArea.read(br, "jTextArea");

            System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

When I comment out this "jTextArea.read(br, "jTextArea");" println works properly and prints out the first line. But in normal case It prints null.
P.S: "file" is my instance variable. There is no problem with this variable, it works properly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedReader br` object has reached its end after being read. So, not the `br` is `null`, but it's current line, which you're trying to read by `br.readLine()`. Otherwise a `NullPointerException` would be thrown on calling `br.readLine()`.
You need to reinitialize BufferedReader and got the first line printed:

```
private void Calculate() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    jTextArea.read(br, "jTextArea");
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

Comment: Oww how I missed this. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help!  Good luck in programming!